# looking for a tutorial for installation of civiCRM for wordpress on NAS Synology

Tags: wordpress

Iam looking for a tutorial for installation of civiCRM for wordpress on NAS Synology.
Could you hep me. is it possible ?
jf briois

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any guides for installing on NAS Synology but general installation instructions are at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/

It looks like you could either try to install in the Synology Web Station or create a Linux VM.